# Aspect Based Sentiment Classification

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, sentiment-analysis, classification

Are there any services which provide aspect-sentiment of the sentence? 
If the sentence/review is talking about multiple aspects, all the aspects with their sentiments (Positive, Negative, Neutral should be the classes) are expected in the output. 
I'm looking for something which is more cognitive than just a key word based engine for aspect (umm, may be using word vectors?) and more than just fixed lists for sentiment classification (like using robust ML and NLP techniques here).

Please let me know of all the products that do the job (I can provide the data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this http://xpresso.abzooba.com/XpressoOnWeb/ for aspect based sentimental analysis.

Comment: This is awesome. They have so many core domains built up. Such a life-saver! Thanks Potter.

Comment: You are welcome, Keeth.